# Failure to execute a zip-file with an archive comment

Tags: python

For some reason it seems that Python (2 and 3) fails to recognize a zipped python file if it contains an archive comment.

Is there a way to make this work without removing the comment from the archive?

Minimal working example:

`__main__.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello world!')
```

Compressing to a zip file:

```
zip archive.zip __main__.py
```

Executing this works:

```
$ python archive.zip
Hello World!
```

However, after adding a comment to the archive execution fails:

```
$ echo "comment" | zip --archive-comment archive.zip
$ python archive.zip
  File "archive.zip", line 1
    PK
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Removing the comment makes the same archive work again.